# Mostrar mensaje que envia el servidor con SocketIO en android

Tags: android, android-studio, socket.io

Estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje desde mi servidor hecho en nodejs, al iniciar mi servidor el mensaje lo muestro en consola pero quiero saber como hago que ese mensaje se muestre en mi smartphone android

esto es lo que tengo

servidor:

```
var array = {"nombre":"jorge pedro"};
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.broadcast.emit('primero',array);
    console.log(array);
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Usuario desconectado con id: '+socket.id);
    })
})
```

y esto hago en mi clase java

```
socket.on("primero", ver);

    private Emitter.Listener ver = new Emitter.Listener(){

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            String message;
            try {
                message = data.getString("nombre").toString();
                Toast.makeText(Menu.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // return;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

La idea es que cuando un telefono se conecte al servidor, éste le envie el array y me sale este error Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

¿Como lo puedo resolver? de antemano agradezco su ayuda

socketio de com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0 para android